# Prove by a combinatorial argument that $(n-r){n \choose r}=n{n-1 \choose r}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

> Prove by a combinatorial argument $$(n-r){n \choose r}=n{n-1 \choose r}$$

**My attempt:**

We have two ways of count the number of persons forms a committee of a group $n$ of people.

Here I'm a little confused, because I don't know how interpret the multiplication by $(n-r)$ here. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the **RHS**

- we choose one president ($n$ choiches) and then form a committee of $r$ out of n-1

On the **LHS**

- we form a committee of $r$ out of $n$ and then choose a president from the others $n-r$

Comment: I don't see very clear the LHS. We choice a commite of $(n-r)$ choices. Then we choose a president for a group of n persons...? Thanks for your answer gimusi.

Comment: @Bvss12 We are simply applying the rule of product we can choose r people in (n,r) ways and for each of these a president in (n-r) ways thus the total number of ways is given by the product. Try with some small number to verify the reasoning.